# simple html dom parsing variables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, simple-html-dom

I have a big problem, and I not find any solution to solve it. I am using pyro cms 2.2 (codeigniter engine) and I would like to parse specified content at the blog view.php template. I already added the simple html dom to the library. With normal $url address there is no problem, parsing is successful. But if I replace a part of the url (like `$url = 'http://www.address.com/{{category:country}}';` then system can't view my variable: ( `{{category:country}}`. But if I print out with an echo, then I see that my url is correct, like address.com/germany. I tried with cURL also, but nothing changed.

Yesterday I asked this here on stackoverflow.com, but we not found any solution, just I got an advice about I need to find a function which enable parse strings. My question: There is any solution to use strings at simple html dom url's? Or if not then there is any other solution to parse html pages with special string support (like address.com/{{category:country}}.

I need some help about how can enable parse strings, or some other idea about how can I parse specified url (url address + the variables from mysql database) at the template.php. Many thanks.

```
 {{ theme:partial name="aside" }}

    {{ post }}

    <?php


    ini_set("user_agent", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) 

    Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17");

    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $url = 'http://address.com/{{category:country}}';


    echo $url;


    ?>

    <article class="single_post">   
        <h5>{{ theme:image file="link.png" }} {{ title }}<small><a href="{{ base:url }}blog" title="Back to the blog">&larr; Back</a></small></h5>

        <div class="post_date">
            <span class="date">
                {{ theme:image file="date.png" }}
                About {{ helper:timespan timestamp=created_on }} ago.
            </span>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="post_body">
            {{ body }}
        </div>

        <div class="post_meta">
            {{ if keywords }}
                {{ theme:image file="tags.png" }}
                <span class="tags">
                    {{ keywords }}
                </span>
            {{ endif }}
        </div>

        <?php if (Settings::get('enable_comments')): ?> 

            <div id="existing-comments">
                <h4><?php echo lang('comments:title') ?></h4>
                <?php echo $this->comments->display() ?>
            </div>      


            <?php if ($form_display): ?>
                <?php echo $this->comments->form() ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo sprintf(lang('blog:disabled_after'), strtolower(lang('global:duration:'.str_replace(' ', '-', $post[0]['comments_enabled'])))) ?>
            <?php endif ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </article>

    {{ /post }}
```

Comment: `{{ }}` is for variables in **HTML**. You can't produce dynamic PHP using them.

Comment: Then how can I parse websites with special variables, have you other idea?

Comment: I'd be VERY surprised if CI didn't have some php-specific way of getting those template variables accessible in php code. it'd be `$url = '...' . get_ci_variable('category:country')` or whatever.

Comment: I did not find any other solution